# Is it best practice to explicitly declare variable types on declaration?

Tags: swift, variables, declaration

I am new to the Swift language, trying to develop healthy programming habits while coding.

Is it best practice to explicitly declare variable types on declaration? For example:

```
var str:String = "likeThis"
```

Or would this be acceptable:

```
var str= "likeThis"
```

Comment: Whatever you do, be consistent.  I think `var str: String = "likeThis"` might be redundant and unnecessary in almost all cases.  An except might be made for numeric types.  Sometimes you explicitly need an `NSInteger` or `CGFloat`, and Swift won't implicitly cast.

Comment: `if ((1 as Int + 1 as Int == 2 as Int) as Bool) == true { println("Types where the context makes them obvious just get in the way of readability" as String) as Void }`

Answer (score 3):

As you know, either option is acceptable. However, standard practice that I have seen is to not declare variable types unless necessary, with the rationale that these extraneous tokens reduce readability.

Here, it is unnecessary because the compiler will infer the variable type. [Ray Wenderlich's Swift style guide](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#type-inference) agrees.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID310):

> It is rare that you need to write type annotations in practice. If you provide an initial value for a constant or variable at the point that it is defined, Swift can almost always infer the type to be used for that constant or variable, as described in [Type Safety and Type Inference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID322).

And with an example from [the same guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID310):

```
var currentLoginAttempt = 0
```

It looks like letting the compiler infer the type with `var str= "likeThis"` is perfectly good practice.

**Disclaimer:** I am also new to Swift and this answer was based solely on what I've learned in class and from reading the [Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309). I've no professional experience with Swift.

Answer (score -1):

***Variables vs. Constants in Swift***

```
var str = "likeThis" // variable
let str = "likeThis" // constant
```

Declaring things with `let` whenever possible is *best practice*, because that will allow the compiler to perform optimizations that it wouldn’t be able to do otherwise. So remember: prefer `let`!

***Explicit vs. Inferred Typing***

So far, we haven’t explicitly set any types for these constants and variables, because the compiler had enough information to infer it automatically.

For example, because you set `str` to `"likeThis"`, the compiler knows `"likeThis"` is a String, so it set the type of `str` to a String for you automatically.

However, you can set the type explicitly if you want. Try this out by replacing the line that sets tutorialTeam to the following:

```
let str: String = "likeThis"
```

You have wondered if you should set types explicitly, or let the compiler infer the types for you. We believe it’s *better practice* to let the compiler infer types automatically where possible, because then you get one of the main advantages of Swift: concise and easy to read code.

Because of this, switch the line back to inferred typing:

```
let str = "likeThis"
```

Comment: `var myAgeOnFriday` with nothing else on the line will not compile.

Comment: @nhgrif , I know it is not going to compile. I have just processed from `var myAgeOnFriday` to `var myAgeOnFriday : Int = 23` in order to explain the whole process of declaring a variable. They are just steps: `var myAgeOnFriday` -> `var myAgeOnFriday : Int` -> `var myAgeOnFriday : Int = 23`. Please read the complete answer, then judge it and down vote it.

Comment: Swift is a type inferred language. You don't need to tell it that 23 is an Integer. For better readability it allows you to omit the type in such obvious cases

Comment: @nhgrif no need to process from `var myAgeOnFriday ` to `var myAgeOnFriday : Int = 23`, my answer now seems to be more obvious and concise.